# What is this very nice looking cactus/succulent?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I inherited this hardy little succulent and I don't know what it is. It's draught tolerant, healthy, and has survived me raising it so I know it's a real survivor.

[image]

Any ideas would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a Stapeliad of some sort; a succulent from south Africa. I find them hard to differentiate. I just got a few recently. The flowers are the best part; star-shaped and fuzzy. Sometimes you get a bonus and the flowers smell like rotting meat! That's why they call them "carrion flower" plants.

Yours looks like it's doing quite well.

Answer (score 0):

[Stapelia Grandiflora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stapelia_grandiflora), a member of the Asclepiad family - not a cactus as it lacks [areoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Areole).

It seems that it grew-up in shade: I don't see much fine hair (trichomes) on the skin. Usually the hair and rough surface are a response to strong sunlight. For better identification give it more light and see how its outer skin changes appearance.